# HTTP response body downcast to text/plain if string object

Tags: azure-functions

Given a string response

```
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
```

In v3 this will be downcast to `"content-type = text/plain"` when `"accept /"` is requested. In earlier versions this will default to `"content-type = application/json"`

Now the response body is `Hello, {name}` instead of `"Hello {name}"`.

This can upset brittle client code that assumes JSON will be returned.

If the accept header is set to `"application/json"` the response matches the request.

Is it possible to prefer JSON over text if no preference is stated?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [sadgit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6904#issuecomment-728938010), for workaround:

```
let CreateJPResponse (req: HttpRequestMessage) (status: HttpStatusCode, payload: _) =
        match req.Headers.Accept.ToString().Trim() with
        | null
        | ""
        | "*/*" ->
            let result = new JsonResult(payload)
            result.StatusCode <- (int status) |> Nullable
            result :> IActionResult
        | _ ->
            let result = new ObjectResult(payload)
            result.StatusCode <- (int status) |> Nullable
            result :> IActionResult
```

This is already an open issue at GitHub [Breaking Change: HTTP response body downcast to text/plain if string object](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6904)